# Should i use switchMap, flatMap or any other rxjs operator in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two streams of data, second one depends on first one, but i want to be able to catch a change of second one. I wrote 2 functions for creating observables. I am wondering if this implementation is correct.

```
firstObservable(){
  ...
};
secondObservable(someValue){
  ...
}
let subscription = firstObservable().switchMap(r => {
  if (r.someValue){
    return secondObservable(r.someValue);
  }else{
    return Observable.empty();
  }
}).subscribe( ... );
```

Comment: Sounds like you would want switchMap rather than flatMap. The big difference between them is that switchMap will complete the second observable (inner observable) any time the first (source) emits. FlatMap will not complete the stale second observables (inner observables) when the first (source) emits so they will keep emitting.

Comment: It works, i'm just not sure if the implementation is good, i don't use flatMap because Observable that i am using is from other source and i get an error when someValue is undefined because Observable empty doesn't have same type as first and second Observable.

Comment: What do you mean by "good" outside of it working? Not clear on what you are going for. It seems to be the right approach. Only other thing is if you don't want the stream to emit when `r.someValue` is falsy then you could just filter it before the switchmap like this: `firstObservable().filter(r => r.someValue).switchMap(r => secondObservable(r.someValue));`.

Answer (score 0):

If you could be more specific about what you are asking it would help but from what I understand it looks fine.

I think that you probably want to use switchMap instead of flatMap. FlatMap will maintain multiple inner subscriptions while SwitchMap will only maintain a subscription to the latest inner observable. So if you want to only get values from the inner observable based on the output of the source then switchMap will do that.

Not sure of your use cases but you might want to consider applying a filter instead of returning Observable.empty().

Here is an example:

```js
const firstObservable = Rx.Observable.create((o) => {
  o.next();
  setTimeout(() => o.next(1), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => o.next(), 2000);
  setTimeout(() => o.next(2), 3000);
  setTimeout(() => o.complete(), 4000);
}).do(console.log.bind(null, 'first: next'),
    console.log.bind(null, 'first: error'),
    console.log.bind(null, 'first: complete'));
const secondObservable = (x) => Rx.Observable.interval(x * 500).take(5)
  .do(console.log.bind(null, 'second: next'),
    console.log.bind(null, 'second: error'),
    console.log.bind(null, 'second: complete'));

firstObservable.filter(x => x).switchMap(x => secondObservable(x))
  .subscribe(console.log.bind(null, 'stream: next'),
    console.log.bind(null, 'stream: error'),
    console.log.bind(null, 'stream: complete'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually, switchMap does **not** complete (send a complete event) to the internal observable upon switching. If you used operators on the internal that depend on the complete event (e.g toArray), it will not trigger. In your example, the complete event is coming from `.take(5)` not from `switchMap`.

Comment: I surmise that switchMap is designed this way, to handle cases where the switched inner is derived from the same source but, say, with different operators. If switchMap completed this source on first switch, the second inner would no longer emit.

Comment: @RichardMatsen Good point. I was more focused on the effect than the completion being called. I updated the answer.

Comment: It's easy to miss it - I posted an answer using `switchMap(x => src.buffer(...` and found that the last buffer of the first inner was being lost.